# FOR loop and string concatenating with JavaScript gives me an undefined value

Tags: javascript

I have the array

```
var data = [name, address, city, country];
```

And the loop

```
var columns;
for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
    columns += "data[" + i + "], ";
}
columns = columns.slice(0, -2);
alert(columns);
```

The alert message says

```
undefineddata[0], data[1], data[2], data[3]
```

What am I doing wrong here? I want to remove the undefined...

Answer (score 17, accepted):

You need to *start* with an empty string, like this:

```
var columns = "";
```

Right now what you have is basically equivalent to:

```
var columns = undefined;
```

Which when concatenated to a string, gives you `"undefined"`.