# How to avoid undefined in string concatenation?

Tags: javascript

I'm iterating over an object and I want to concatenate the name of the service. This is my code:

```
var servizi;

for(var i = 0; i < appointment.id_services.length; i++)
{
    servizi += appointment.id_services[i].name + " ";
}
```

Now the problem's that I got this result:

> undefined hair cut

In my object there's only hair and cut, why I get undefined also?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [FOR loop and string concatenating with JavaScript gives me an undefined value](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3992973/for-loop-and-string-concatenating-with-javascript-gives-me-an-undefined-value)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You get undefined because you declared an uninitialized variable, and then added to it (twice).

Initialize the declared variable as an empty string first

```
var servizi = "";
```

Answer (score 3):

intialize variable to empty string

```
var servizi = "";
```

Answer (score 1):

Uninitialized variables always begin with a value of undefined.

```
let servizi; // typeof(servizi) is undefined
```

So when you attempt to concatenate a string onto an undefined variable, the word "undefined" is converted to a string and added to the start. To avoid this, initialize the variable as an empty string.

```
let servizi = "";
```