# Why does this 'undefined' comes in the HTML?

Tags: javascript, undefined

I am a beginner in javascript. I was doing a simple js code.  The HTML output has an 'undefined' element. I couldn't understand why it came. This script is to display the details about inventors in an HTML table.

```js
const inventors = [
  { first: 'Albert', last: 'Einstein', year: 1879, passed: 1955 },
  { first: 'Isaac', last: 'Newton', year: 1643, passed: 1727 },
  { first: 'Galileo', last: 'Galilei', year: 1564, passed: 1642 },
  { first: 'Marie', last: 'Curie', year: 1867, passed: 1934 },
  { first: 'Johannes', last: 'Kepler', year: 1571, passed: 1630 },
  { first: 'Nicolaus', last: 'Copernicus', year: 1473, passed: 1543 },
  { first: 'Max', last: 'Planck', year: 1858, passed: 1947 },
  { first: 'Katherine', last: 'Blodgett', year: 1898, passed: 1979 },
  { first: 'Ada', last: 'Lovelace', year: 1815, passed: 1852 },
  { first: 'Sarah E.', last: 'Goode', year: 1855, passed: 1905 },
  { first: 'Lise', last: 'Meitner', year: 1878, passed: 1968 },
  { first: 'Hanna', last: 'Hammarström', year: 1829, passed: 1909 }
];

const people = ['Beck, Glenn', 'Becker, Carl', 'Beckett, Samuel', 'Beddoes, Mick', 'Beecher, Henry', 'Beethoven, Ludwig', 'Begin, Menachem', 'Belloc, Hilaire', 'Bellow, Saul', 'Benchley, Robert', 'Benenson, Peter', 'Ben-Gurion, David', 'Benjamin, Walter', 'Benn, Tony', 'Bennington, Chester', 'Benson, Leana', 'Bent, Silas', 'Bentsen, Lloyd', 'Berger, Ric', 'Bergman, Ingmar', 'Berio, Luciano', 'Berle, Milton', 'Berlin, Irving', 'Berne, Eric', 'Bernhard, Sandra', 'Berra, Yogi', 'Berry, Halle', 'Berry, Wendell', 'Bethea, Erin', 'Bevan, Aneurin', 'Bevel, Ken', 'Biden, Joseph', 'Bierce, Ambrose', 'Biko, Steve', 'Billings, Josh', 'Biondo, Frank', 'Birrell, Augustine', 'Black Elk', 'Blair, Robert', 'Blair, Tony', 'Blake, William'];


const fullNames = inventors.map(function(invent) {
  return [invent.first, invent.last, invent.year, invent.passed];
});
console.log(fullNames[0][0]);
var tableCells;
var cellContent;
for (var i = 0; i < fullNames.length; i++) {
  cellContent = '';
  for (var j = 0; j < fullNames[i].length; j++) {

    cellContent = cellContent + '<td>' + fullNames[i][j] + '</td>';
  }
  tableCells = tableCells + '<tr>' + cellContent + '</td>';
}
document.getElementById('demo').innerHTML = tableCells;
```

```html
<div>
  <table id="demo">

  </table>
</div>
```

Comment: just define tableCells to null or blank like var tableCells = '';

Comment: @Bhautik Defining `tableCells` as `null` will just cause the loop to print `null` instead of `undefined`.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [FOR loop and string concatenating with JavaScript gives me an undefined value](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3992973/for-loop-and-string-concatenating-with-javascript-gives-me-an-undefined-value)

Comment: @Xufox You are right sorry mate

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Initialize tableCells as empty string

```
var tableCells = "";
```

else in first iteration the value will be like this

```
tableCells = /*tableCells */ "undefined" + '<tr>' + cellContent + '</td>';
```

```js
const inventors = [
  { first: 'Albert', last: 'Einstein', year: 1879, passed: 1955 },
  { first: 'Isaac', last: 'Newton', year: 1643, passed: 1727 },
  { first: 'Galileo', last: 'Galilei', year: 1564, passed: 1642 },
  { first: 'Marie', last: 'Curie', year: 1867, passed: 1934 },
  { first: 'Johannes', last: 'Kepler', year: 1571, passed: 1630 },
  { first: 'Nicolaus', last: 'Copernicus', year: 1473, passed: 1543 },
  { first: 'Max', last: 'Planck', year: 1858, passed: 1947 },
  { first: 'Katherine', last: 'Blodgett', year: 1898, passed: 1979 },
  { first: 'Ada', last: 'Lovelace', year: 1815, passed: 1852 },
  { first: 'Sarah E.', last: 'Goode', year: 1855, passed: 1905 },
  { first: 'Lise', last: 'Meitner', year: 1878, passed: 1968 },
  { first: 'Hanna', last: 'Hammarström', year: 1829, passed: 1909 }
];

const people = ['Beck, Glenn', 'Becker, Carl', 'Beckett, Samuel', 'Beddoes, Mick', 'Beecher, Henry', 'Beethoven, Ludwig', 'Begin, Menachem', 'Belloc, Hilaire', 'Bellow, Saul', 'Benchley, Robert', 'Benenson, Peter', 'Ben-Gurion, David', 'Benjamin, Walter', 'Benn, Tony', 'Bennington, Chester', 'Benson, Leana', 'Bent, Silas', 'Bentsen, Lloyd', 'Berger, Ric', 'Bergman, Ingmar', 'Berio, Luciano', 'Berle, Milton', 'Berlin, Irving', 'Berne, Eric', 'Bernhard, Sandra', 'Berra, Yogi', 'Berry, Halle', 'Berry, Wendell', 'Bethea, Erin', 'Bevan, Aneurin', 'Bevel, Ken', 'Biden, Joseph', 'Bierce, Ambrose', 'Biko, Steve', 'Billings, Josh', 'Biondo, Frank', 'Birrell, Augustine', 'Black Elk', 'Blair, Robert', 'Blair, Tony', 'Blake, William'];


const fullNames = inventors.map(function(invent) {
  return [invent.first, invent.last, invent.year, invent.passed];
});
console.log(fullNames[0][0]);
var tableCells = "";
var cellContent;
for (var i = 0; i < fullNames.length; i++) {
  cellContent = '';
  for (var j = 0; j < fullNames[i].length; j++) {

    cellContent = cellContent + '<td>' + fullNames[i][j] + '</td>';
  }
  tableCells = tableCells + '<tr>' + cellContent + '</td>';
}
document.getElementById('demo').innerHTML = tableCells;
```

```html
<div>
  <table id="demo">

  </table>
</div>
```

```js
const inventors = [
  { first: 'Albert', last: 'Einstein', year: 1879, passed: 1955 },
  { first: 'Isaac', last: 'Newton', year: 1643, passed: 1727 },
  { first: 'Galileo', last: 'Galilei', year: 1564, passed: 1642 },
  { first: 'Marie', last: 'Curie', year: 1867, passed: 1934 },
  { first: 'Johannes', last: 'Kepler', year: 1571, passed: 1630 },
  { first: 'Nicolaus', last: 'Copernicus', year: 1473, passed: 1543 },
  { first: 'Max', last: 'Planck', year: 1858, passed: 1947 },
  { first: 'Katherine', last: 'Blodgett', year: 1898, passed: 1979 },
  { first: 'Ada', last: 'Lovelace', year: 1815, passed: 1852 },
  { first: 'Sarah E.', last: 'Goode', year: 1855, passed: 1905 },
  { first: 'Lise', last: 'Meitner', year: 1878, passed: 1968 },
  { first: 'Hanna', last: 'Hammarström', year: 1829, passed: 1909 }
];

const people = ['Beck, Glenn', 'Becker, Carl', 'Beckett, Samuel', 'Beddoes, Mick', 'Beecher, Henry', 'Beethoven, Ludwig', 'Begin, Menachem', 'Belloc, Hilaire', 'Bellow, Saul', 'Benchley, Robert', 'Benenson, Peter', 'Ben-Gurion, David', 'Benjamin, Walter', 'Benn, Tony', 'Bennington, Chester', 'Benson, Leana', 'Bent, Silas', 'Bentsen, Lloyd', 'Berger, Ric', 'Bergman, Ingmar', 'Berio, Luciano', 'Berle, Milton', 'Berlin, Irving', 'Berne, Eric', 'Bernhard, Sandra', 'Berra, Yogi', 'Berry, Halle', 'Berry, Wendell', 'Bethea, Erin', 'Bevan, Aneurin', 'Bevel, Ken', 'Biden, Joseph', 'Bierce, Ambrose', 'Biko, Steve', 'Billings, Josh', 'Biondo, Frank', 'Birrell, Augustine', 'Black Elk', 'Blair, Robert', 'Blair, Tony', 'Blake, William'];


const fullNames = inventors.map(function(invent) {
  return [invent.first, invent.last, invent.year, invent.passed];
});
console.log(fullNames[0][0]);
var tableCells;
var cellContent;
for (var i = 0; i < fullNames.length; i++) {
  cellContent = '';
  for (var j = 0; j < fullNames[i].length; j++) {

    cellContent = cellContent + '<td>' + fullNames[i][j] + '</td>';
  }
  tableCells = tableCells + '<tr>' + cellContent + '</td>';
}
document.getElementById('demo').innerHTML = tableCells;
```

```html
<div>
  <table id="demo">

  </table>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

You're not initializing `tableCells` to anything, so when you do `tableCells = tableCells + '<tr>' + cellContent + '</td>';`, the first iteration results in `tableCells = undefined + '<tr>' + cellContent + '</td>';`.

Initialize it properly instead:

```
var tableCells = '';
```

```js
const inventors = [
  { first: 'Albert', last: 'Einstein', year: 1879, passed: 1955 },
  { first: 'Isaac', last: 'Newton', year: 1643, passed: 1727 },
  { first: 'Galileo', last: 'Galilei', year: 1564, passed: 1642 },
  { first: 'Marie', last: 'Curie', year: 1867, passed: 1934 },
  { first: 'Johannes', last: 'Kepler', year: 1571, passed: 1630 },
  { first: 'Nicolaus', last: 'Copernicus', year: 1473, passed: 1543 },
  { first: 'Max', last: 'Planck', year: 1858, passed: 1947 },
  { first: 'Katherine', last: 'Blodgett', year: 1898, passed: 1979 },
  { first: 'Ada', last: 'Lovelace', year: 1815, passed: 1852 },
  { first: 'Sarah E.', last: 'Goode', year: 1855, passed: 1905 },
  { first: 'Lise', last: 'Meitner', year: 1878, passed: 1968 },
  { first: 'Hanna', last: 'Hammarström', year: 1829, passed: 1909 }
];

const people = ['Beck, Glenn', 'Becker, Carl', 'Beckett, Samuel', 'Beddoes, Mick', 'Beecher, Henry', 'Beethoven, Ludwig', 'Begin, Menachem', 'Belloc, Hilaire', 'Bellow, Saul', 'Benchley, Robert', 'Benenson, Peter', 'Ben-Gurion, David', 'Benjamin, Walter', 'Benn, Tony', 'Bennington, Chester', 'Benson, Leana', 'Bent, Silas', 'Bentsen, Lloyd', 'Berger, Ric', 'Bergman, Ingmar', 'Berio, Luciano', 'Berle, Milton', 'Berlin, Irving', 'Berne, Eric', 'Bernhard, Sandra', 'Berra, Yogi', 'Berry, Halle', 'Berry, Wendell', 'Bethea, Erin', 'Bevan, Aneurin', 'Bevel, Ken', 'Biden, Joseph', 'Bierce, Ambrose', 'Biko, Steve', 'Billings, Josh', 'Biondo, Frank', 'Birrell, Augustine', 'Black Elk', 'Blair, Robert', 'Blair, Tony', 'Blake, William'];


const fullNames = inventors.map(function(invent) {
  return [invent.first, invent.last, invent.year, invent.passed];
});
console.log(fullNames[0][0]);
var tableCells = '';
var cellContent;
for (var i = 0; i < fullNames.length; i++) {
  cellContent = '';
  for (var j = 0; j < fullNames[i].length; j++) {

    cellContent = cellContent + '<td>' + fullNames[i][j] + '</td>';
  }
  tableCells = tableCells + '<tr>' + cellContent + '</td>';
}
document.getElementById('demo').innerHTML = tableCells;
```

```html
<div>
  <table id="demo">

  </table>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

you have must initialise variable befor print
`var tableCells = "somthing";`

then `tableCells = tableCells + '<tr>' + cellContent + '</td>';`

Answer (score 1):

Just do a small changes . As you are appending a string to a variable that dont have any value defined. 
So initially that value on that variable in 'undefined'. So the final string is generated like : undefined + ****** . That's why you got this.
Just write

```
var tableCells = "";
```

instead of

```
var tableCells;
```

and it will work :

Jsfiddle link : https://jsfiddle.net/h15qsbj2/1/