# Why does my http response add undefined to the beginning of my request payload?

Tags: node.js, http, xmlhttprequest

I have a node.js server responding to and email input http request. When I recieve the request payload I get the intented email input with undefined at the beginning: "undefinedcrosati@gmail.com"

My Server route looks like this:

```
else if (request.url === '/email'){
    var email_Addr
    request.on('data', (data)=>{ // adding chunks of data to request body
        email_Addr += data.toString();
        console.log('server stream email', email_Addr) // results in "undefinedcrosati@gmail.com"
    });
    request.on('end',(data)=>{
        console.log(email_Addr) // results in "undefinedcrosati@gmail.com"
        emailData(email_Addr)
    });

    response.write('Email Data')
    response.end(email_Addr)
}
```

On the client app I can see the http header in chrome dev tools as I intended to send it ex: crosati@gmail.com .

Since I am just turning the buffer into a string I am not doing anything else to the data. What is going on here?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [FOR loop and string concatenating with JavaScript gives me an undefined value](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3992973/for-loop-and-string-concatenating-with-javascript-gives-me-an-undefined-value)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Define your variable `email_Addr` as an empty string if you want to append strings to it:

`var email_Addr = '';`

Otherwise that variable is `undefined` and if you treat it as a string, Node will convert the variable to the string "undefined".