# JQuery outputting "undefined" onto page

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I have a jquery script looping through my data.json file to find related enteries but on my webpage it is outputting "undefined". I tried assigning the output variable to null but it then just outputs null. How can I just get it to show the actual resuts? Here is my code

```
$(document).ready(function(){

$('#search').keydown(function(){

    $.getJSON("data.json", function(data){
        var search = $('#search').val();
        var regex = new RegExp(search, 'i');
        var currentCategory = "Logistics";
        var output;

        $.each(data, function(key, val){
            if ((val.title.search(regex) != -1) && val.category == currentCategory) {
                output += "<li><img src='"+val.img+"'><h2>"+val.title+"</h2></li>";
            }
        });

        $('ul.news').html(output);
    });
});
});
```

Comment: Try this: `var output = '';`

Comment: @DacreDenny worked! i tried that earlier and it didn't, old js must have been cached or something. Cheers!

Comment: You're welcome :)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [FOR loop and string concatenating with JavaScript gives me an undefined value](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3992973/for-loop-and-string-concatenating-with-javascript-gives-me-an-undefined-value)

Comment: Do you really want to make a http request for the same file every key press?

Answer (score 0):

This is because your output variable is undefined when you do not found appropriate data. So handle it elegantly to show proper result to End User.

```
    $(document).ready(function(){

            $('#search').keydown(function(){

                $.getJSON("data.json", function(data){
                    var search = $('#search').val();
                    var regex = new RegExp(search, 'i');
                    var currentCategory = "Logistics";
                    var output; //<-- This is undefined

                    $.each(data, function(key, val){
                        if ((val.title.search(regex) != -1) && val.category == currentCategory) {
                            output += "<li><img src='"+val.img+"'><h2>"+val.title+"</h2></li>";
                        }
                    });                   
                   $('ul.news').html(output || "<li> No Records found</li>"); 
                   // Used "||" to set alternate html if value of 'output' variable is [null, undefined, 0, '']
                });
            });
            });
```